# MouseHover on a child node

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I am doing an win form application. I am using a tree view  and my tree view is like

Root 
|-> Child
     |->a.txt
|->Child1
     |-> a.txt

and so on

Now if i had my mouse over any sub child of that containing the text file i would like to show the path of that file saved on a tool tip.

I used the following code but it does not work properly when i move my mouse on to the other nodes that tool tip is still getting displayed any solution for this

My code

```
    private void treeViewACH_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeViewACH.SelectedNode.Text == "ACHFile")
        {
            ttpShow.RemoveAll();
        }
        if (treeViewACH.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
        {
            string strSwitch = treeViewACH.SelectedNode.Parent.Text;

            switch (strSwitch)
            {
                case "FileHeader":
                    {
                        Node = treeViewACH.SelectedNode.Text;
                        strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                        strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
                        strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
                        strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\ACH\\" + Node;
                        if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
                        {
                            ttpShow.SetToolTip(treeViewACH, strFilePath);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer for this just modified the above code